# Find entities based on "labels" in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12, relational-division

Say I have two tables in Postgresql 12, one which stores base data of a `project` and each of these `project`s  may have an arbitrary set of `label`s:

```
CREATE TABLE projects (
  id SERIAL,
  title TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE labels (
  id SERIAL,
  projects_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES projects(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  key VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL,
  value TEXT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (projects_id, key)
);
```

Now I want to create a query which returns all `projects` which match **all** of multiple key/value combinations from `labels`.
I would like to use an "arbitrary" number (say at least 5) of label matches.

Selecting `projects` matching exactly one label is easy:

```
SELECT 
  p.id, p.title 
FROM projects p 
JOIN labels l ON l.projects_id = p.id 
WHERE l.key = 'k1' AND l.value = 'v1';
```

Just using

```
SELECT p.id, p.title
FROM projects p
JOIN labels l ON l.projects_id = p.id 
WHERE 
  l.key = 'k1' AND l.value = 'v1' AND 
  l.key = 'k2' AND l.value = 'v2';
```

does not work and I understand why.

What is the best approach here using SQL only?

Comment: `WHERE (l.key, l.value) IN (('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', 'v3') )`? See [Row/Array Comparisons](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html) for more options.

Comment: The current answer is great, but if you want to bone up this is a good read on this type of problem (relational division) https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```sql
select p.*
from projects p
join (
  select projects_id 
  from labels
  where (key, value) in (
    ('k1', 'v1'), -- The list of labels to look for
    ('k2', 'v2'),
    ('k3', 'v3'),
    ('k4', 'v4'),
    ('k5', 'v5')
  )
  having count(*) = 5 -- We want full count of them
  group by projects_id
) x on x.projects_id = p.id
```